Trying to remember old movie with chariots?
I was taken to a double feature as a kid. Now trying to identify the movies.
I have very limited, strange snippets of memories of these films. Both were intense.
-Late sixties or very early seventies.
-First movie involved chariots and slaves. There's a scene where slaves buried to their necks are going to be decapitated by a chariot pulling a blade and the Soldier or whoever goes around and pushes their heads back to get them ready. In another scene, a slave or prisoner (who may be a main character) is held in some kind of "drawer" and a dwarf climbs in to free him or secure him or something.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please split this into 2 questions so they can be answered individually.

First one sounds like caligula, although time frame is wrong.

@JohnP I know the first one, and it ain't Caligula. ;) Just waiting for the split.

You can find both scenes in Samson and the Seven Miracles of the World from 1961:

In his eternal wandering Maciste finds himself in 13th Century China rescuing a Chinese prince and princess from the Tartars and leading the Chinese into a revolt against them.

In one scene, a row of people is buried in the sand and secured with stocks and a bladed chariot beheads them. In another, Maciste is shoved into a tight crypt and secured by a dwarf. Here's the trailer:




@user15964 - You should accept it if it is correct, and you should also split your original question.
